# How to access the item after in a SortedSet

Tags: .net, linq, sortedset

How to access the item after in a SortedSet?

```
string entry;
private SortedSet<string> pastEntriesSS = new SortedSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

entry = entry.Replace("\t", "").TrimStart();
entry = Regex.Replace(entry, @"\s+", " ");
string s = pastEntriesSS.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith(entry.Trim(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
{
    if(string.Compare(s,entry.Trim(),true) == 0)
    {
        // what I what here is the entry after s
        // how do I get the index of s
        int index = -1;
        s = pastEntriesSS.ElementAt(index + 1);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) entry = s;
    }
    else 
        entry = s;
}
```

This is used for an autocomplete and if they hit that tab on an exact match then I want to get the next

I think I was looking at this wrong
This is what I came up with

```
entry = entry.Replace("\t", "").TrimStart();
entry = Regex.Replace(entry, @"\s+", " ");
string s = pastEntriesSS.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith(entry, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
{
    if(string.Compare(s,entry,true) == 0)
    {   // it they tabbed on an  exact match then go to next or prior
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift))
        {
            s = pastEntriesSS.Reverse().FirstOrDefault(x => string.Compare(x, s, true) < 0);
        }
        else
        {
            s = pastEntriesSS.FirstOrDefault(x => string.Compare(x, s, true) > 0);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) entry = s;
    }
    else 
        entry = s;
}
```

Comment: Also, this will find elements based on input that is not necessarily in the set (e.g., if the set contained only "apple" and "cat", the input of "bear" would show "apple" as before and "cat" after, even though "bear" was not itself in the list), but this isn't necessarily a bad thing for a search helper

Comment: @Sam Yes I did think about that and that is the desired behavior.  In the full code and enter key is used to add to the list and actually add the value to the database.  I considered a tab on and item not present to add the item to the list but not add it to the database.  For example the user had a list of possible values they wanted to key in.

Comment: @Sam consider they enter b and just want to get to the first b but have not reason for b on the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the logic provided by the asker, here is a way to provide `ElementBefore` and `ElementAfter` access to any `SortedSet` using extension methods:

```
public static class BeforeAfterExtension
{
    //The true workhorse of the code!
    public static T ElementBefore<T>(this SortedSet<T> mySet, T val, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        //we are getting the first element el such that it is before
        //the provided value val. We must reverse the set because
        //otherwise, the first element in the set is always the first
        //to be less than the provided value.
        return mySet.Reverse().FirstOrDefault(el => comparer.Compare(el, val) < 0);
    }

    //Contains all the actual logic
    public static T ElementAfter<T>(this SortedSet<T> mySet, T val, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        //we are getting the first element el such that it is after
        //the provided value val.
        return mySet.FirstOrDefault(el => comparer.Compare(el, val) > 0);
    }

    //use the existing logic, but use the default comparer for the set
    public static T ElementBefore<T>(this SortedSet<T> mySet, T val)
    {
        return ElementBefore(mySet, val, mySet.Comparer);
    }

    //use the existing logic, but use the default comparer for the set
    public static T ElementAfter<T>(this SortedSet<T> mySet, T val)
    {
        return ElementAfter(mySet, val, mySet.Comparer);
    }

    //provide a condition that the element must already exist in the set
    //Consider a set of strings containing only "apple" and "cat"
    //without forcing the element to exist in the set, we could search for
    //the element before "bear" and get "apple" even though "bear" is not
    //in the set. Forcing the element to exist by setting mustExist=true
    //would return null if the element is not there already
    public static T ElementBefore<T>(this SortedSet<T> mySet, T val, bool mustExist, IComparer<T> comparer) {
    {
        if (mustExist)
        {
            if (mySet.Contains(val))
            {
                //take advantage of existing logic
                return ElementBefore(mySet, val, comparer);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //take advantage of existing logic
            return ElementBefore(mySet, val, comparer);
        }
    }

    //provide a condition that the element must already exist in the set
    //Consider a set of strings containing only "apple" and "cat"
    //without forcing the element to exist in the set, we could search for
    //the element after "bear" and get "cat" even though "bear" is not
    //in the set. Forcing the element to exist by setting mustExist=true
    //would return null if the element is not there already
    public static T ElementBefore<T>(this SortedSet<T> mySet, T val, bool mustExist, IComparer<T> comparer) {
    {
        if (mustExist)
        {
            if (mySet.Contains(val))
            {
                //take advantage of existing logic
                return ElementAfter(mySet, val, comparer);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //take advantage of existing logic
            return ElementAfter(mySet, val, comparer);
        }
    }

    //just use the default set comparer
    public static T ElementBefore<T>(this SortedSet<T> mySet, T val, bool mustExist)
    {
        //take advantage of existing logic
        return ElementBefore(mySet, val, mustExist, mySet.Comparer);
    }

    //just use the default set comparer
    public static T ElementAfter<T>(this SortedSet<T> mySet, T val, bool mustExist)
    {
        //take advantage of existing logic
        return ElementAfter(mySet, val, mustExist, mySet.Comparer);
    }
}
```

There are some additional methods in there that allow the customization of the comparer used, and to require the element exists in the set.

Now all that is required is

```
if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift))
{
    s = pastEntriesSS.ElementBefore(s);
}
else
{
    s = pastEntriesSS.ElementAfter(s);
}
```

and this is extensible to sets containing any kind of object, not just strings

Comment: Let me look at you answer and test it out.   As for add and remove I think just those from the base.  I am not familiar with extension methods so it is going to take me a bit.  Why would you not make a collection that implements SortedSet?

Comment: @Blam you can check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx but you should be able to just add the class to your project and call the new methods directly on your `SortedSet` objects

Comment: Yes I have used Extension methods.  Still going to take me a bit to test how it is used in the real app is a little more complex than the sample I posted.

Comment: I did not fully test this but I believe it to be correct

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to get the index of the value `s`, then retrieve the element right after it.

You could accomplish this with an extension method that retrieves the index of `s`:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static int IndexOf<T>(this SortedSet<T> mySet, T val)
    {
        int index = 0;
        foreach (T el in mySet) {
            if (mySet.Comparer.Compare(el, val) == 0) {
                return index;
            }
            index++;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static int IndexOf<T>(this SortedSet<T> mySet, T val, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        int index = 0;
        foreach (T el in mySet) {
            if (comparer.Equals(val, el)) {
                return index;
            }
            index++;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Which let's you call `IndexOf` on your set:

```
int index = pastEntriesSS.IndexOf(s);
if (index >= 0)
{
    s = pastEntriesSS.ElementAt(index + 1);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) entry = s;
}
```

Comment: What I came up with is going directly to the next item rather than first determining the item.  Please see the update to my question.

Comment: @Blam that is certainly an elegant way to accomplish your goal! I like it, and think you should post an answer to your question with the solution and remove the edit from your question. That will certainly retrieve the element directly following, and avoids all the clunk of the extension method.